# stop() before a highlight is causing the color to not reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
$('#list_item_title', this).stop().effect('highlight', {color: '#8DD2F7'}, 700);
```

This occurs when a user tries to submit with 0 input.length. If the user presses enter several times, the highlights stack up which is why I added stop. Problem now is that the animation stops and the input color is a variation of the highlight color and not the neutral white background.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

`stop()` accepts some parameters.

```
.stop( [clearQueue,] [jumpToEnd] )
```

[stop api documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

You should invoke it in this way:

```
$('#list_item_title', this).stop(false, true).effect('highlight', {color: '#8DD2F7'}, 700);
```

By doing so, your color will be changed directly to `#8DD2F7` when you stop the animation.

Comment: This is all right, but is there any way to revert the color back to initial state (eg. white) after stopping the animation?

Comment: Have you tried something like `.stop().css('color', 'white');`? So stop the animation and immediately after change the color with `.css()`.